# Is the UK legally prevented from having another referendum on Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

Is there a legal reason or law(s) that prevents the United Kingdom from having another referendum on Brexit?

Comment: This is  NOT a duplicate of [that](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33942/whats-the-point-in-holding-a-second-brexit-referendum) question. That one is a "why?" question, and this one is a "is it possible?" question.

Comment: Laws apply to people, not to countries. No law can prevent a state from doing anything.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No. The United Kingdom can hold as many referendums on this subject as it likes, as often as it likes. Obviously there are technicalities and bureaucratic measures that have to be accounted for, and some logistical concerns, but there are no legal restrictions to holding the same referendum after the same referendum again and again.

Comment: The main impediments to having a referendum at present are the lack of time before the Brexit deadline, and the determination of the Prime Minister not to have one.

Comment: +1 for addressing the actual question (the legality). I would suggest providing some explanation of the legal process (e.g. Parliamentary sovereignty, all that is required is an Act of parliament, etc.), but on the other hand this is not law.stackexchange, where the question really ought to have been posted.

Comment: @JohnDallman Another problem is that the country is not facing precisely two options. They could try to stay in the UK, they could accept the deal on the table, they could try to keep negotiating a better deal, they could exit with no deal. It's not clear how to handle such a case with a referendum.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When you want to choose between multiple options with some of them being similar, then [ranked choice voting](https://ballotpedia.org/Ranked-choice_voting_(RCV)) is a possible option.

Comment: @Philipp - The British Public historically haven't been all that keen on forms of PR

Comment: @Valorum the English public; all the devolved assemblies use non-FPTP systems happily

Comment: @pjc50 - "happily" is certainly one way of looking at it. It's certainly popular with minority parties (for obvious reason) but as recently as 2017 the Conservatives were standing on a manifesto of removing STV from the regions and returning them to FPTP. Had May not had such a disastrous election campaign, it's likely that this would have been implemented by now.

Comment: @Valorum as you say, the English are unhappy with it because it empowers other parties; I don't see the devolved assemblies choosing to demand changes to their voting systems ...

Comment: @Valorum: rank-order voting isn't proportional representation.  It simply gives votes a way to express their full set of preferences instead of having to vote strategically if their actual first choice is unlikely to win.  One method for counting such ballets is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method (e.g. used by Debian GNU/Linux developers https://www.debian.org/vote/ with PGP-signed email secret ballots, which actually works well for that technologically-sophisticated group of voters), others include https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting.

Answer (score 26):

The main issue with taking another referendum is not so much that they cannot, but rather that it opens the door to being accused of **trying again until you get the outcome you want**.

Anyone who is loudly in favor of a new referendum can similarly be accused of **not wanting to enact the will of the people** (i.e. the outcome of the first referendum). You only need a minority of "leave" voters who get offended enough to cause a significant uproar over your so-called undemocratic behavior.

If you ask the people for input, they give you an answer, and then you don't want to follow their answer, what is the point of asking them again? Either you're going to get the same answer (which means the second referendum was pointless), or you're going to get the answer you wanted so you can do the thing (remain in the EU) that you think is better (which means referendums are pointless if you're going to do what you want anyway, instead of listening to the people).
In either case, **the second referendum always leads to a situation that suggests that the second referendum is pointless**.

In short, the UK currently finds itself in a position where they're headed in a direction that (a significant subset of) people do not want to go, but everyone's apprehensive of changing direction because they don't want the backlash that comes with being the one who proposed changing direction.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90139/discussion-on-answer-by-flater-is-the-uk-legally-prevented-from-having-another-r).

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't really answer the question. It is making an argument about whether or not the UK *should* have a second referendum, but not the actual question whether it is *legally possible*.

Comment: I upvoted this because the UK is legally prevented from doing a 2nd referendum if the only people who can legally call such a referendum are not willing to. And this answer explain why such legal option is not available in practice.

Comment: You are very wrong. Actually, "voting again" is the basis of parliamentary democracy. That's why you go to vote again every few years, it's because people opinion changes all the time. Obviously, you cannot have referendums on the same topic too often (generally, 4-5 years would be acceptable) and you should probably have a good reason to believe that the opinion has shifted (e.g. non-official polls). Also, politicians should respect the old results until the next referendum actually happens. Any other argumentation is just about excuses.

Comment: @Sulthan: You're comparing apples and oranges. Elections are known to be a repeating vote. Governmental elections specify the term of the election results (e.g. 5 years), but there was no term attached to the result of the Brexit referendum. There is no precedent for leaving/joining the EU to be on a fixed term basis and, if anything, the EU is incentivized to not facilitate that process for their own benefit (stability as opposed to fluctuation).

Comment: You have not proved in any way that a second referendum would be pointless.  Confirmation of the decision if the second referendum went the same way is not pointless.  Allowing people to change their minds, especially in light of the fact that the electorate knew little to nothing about what Brexit would actually mean the first time around, is certainly not pointless.

Comment: @EricNolan: I'm not arguing that it _is_ pointless, but rather that it _can be suggested/argued to be_ pointless, which massively detracts political power from those who wish to have a second referendum. What you call "confirmation", a pro-leave politician is going to call "questioning an established answer".

Comment: @Philipp: The first paragraph states that there is nothing preventing a second referendum from a legal perspective, and segues into the more important point that even though it's legally possible, there are other blocking factors that cause an impasse (which is a _practical_ impossibility, rather than a theoretical/legal one).